# limit of sequence of quotients of sequence that converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=a$$

Prove that if
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{x_{n+1}\over x_n}=L$$
so
$$|L|\le1$$

....

I tried for a long time but i can't prove that. please give me just a hint?

thanks

Comment: You may let $|L|>1$ and argue by contradiction

Comment: @John tried that, but I dont see where the contradiction is.. why is the statement even correct, intuitively?

Comment: @user3697301 Intuitively, it is correct because it would grow faster than an unbounded geometrical summation. Can you continue?

Comment: @chubakueno I thought I can prove this just with the limit definition..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say that $|L|>1$. Then, as @xpaul noted, $|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}|>1$ whenever $n\geq N$. Then, $|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}|>q$ for all $n>N$ for a certain $q>1$. If you are not certain that such a $q$ exists, just use the definition of the limit and take $\epsilon$ arbitrarily small and note that $|L|-\epsilon>1$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon$.  Assume, without loss of generality, that $|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}|>q$ for all $n$.

Now, notice that

$|x_{n}|=|x_1|\cdot |\frac{x_{2}}{x_1}|\cdot|\frac{x_3}{x_2}|\cdot\ldots\cdot|\frac{x_{n}}{x_{n-1}}|>|x_1|\cdot q^{n-1} $ $(1)$

$\lim_{n\to\infty} |x_1|\cdot q^{n-1}=+\infty$

Thus, $x_n$ cannot tend to a finite value.

QED.

Now, I will explain why it is "alright" to assume that $|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}|>q$ for all natural numbers $n$ rather than for all $n>N$.

Now, if it is true for all $n>N$,then it is true except for a finite number of integers. Call it $k$ The value in equation $(1)$ would become

$|x_n|=|x_1|\cdot\ldots\cdot |\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k}|\cdot\ldots|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}|>|x_1|\cdot\ldots\cdot |\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k}|\cdot q^{n-k-1}=c\cdot q^{n-1}$ where $c=|x_1|\cdot\ldots\cdot |\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k}|\cdot q^{-k}$

You can see that $c$ is constant so the limit will still be $+\infty$. Now, you might want to know that a finite number of terms at the "beginning" of the sequence do not, in any way, affect the convergence of that sequence, which is what allowed me to change from $n>N$ to "for all $n$"

Comment: "loss of generality, that |xn+1xn|> for all n." -
greater than what?

Comment: "Then, |xn+1xn|>q for all n>N for a certain q>1."
this is a specific q that works for all n>N, right? but we using it from |x2/x1|. can you elaborate?

Comment: I shall edit my answer to elaborate on your questions (Also made a mistake with writing, sorry.) Tell me if you need anything further after I edit.

Comment: so |x_n| tends to ∞,  so we can conclude (using limit definiton) that x_n itself tends to +∞ or -∞, so it can't converge. Is this correct?

Comment: Not precisely. Take $x_n=n(-1)^n$. It doesn't tend to neither $+\infty$ nor $-\infty$ though $|x_n|$ tends to $+\infty.$ If the absolute value tends to $+\infty$ then $x_n$ gets arbitrarily large (to positive or negative) so it cannot tend to a finite value.

Comment: ok, I see, but how do i prove it formally

Comment: You assume that $x_n$ converges to $L$. But then, since $|x_n|$ tends to $\infty$, for some sufficiently large $N$, $|x_n|>2L$, that is $|x_n-L|\geq|x_n|-L>L$ for all $n>N$. (You know the definition  of the lmiit and why this makes it impossible to tend to $L$, right? If not, just take $\varepsilon<L$.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use argument by contradiction and the definition of the limit. Suppose $|L|>1$. For $\varepsilon_0=|L|-1>0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\big|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\big|=|L|>1$ implies that there is $N>0$ such that 
$$ \big|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\big|>|L|-\varepsilon_0=1 \text{ whenever }n\ge N. $$
Next show $\{|x_n|\}$ is increasing and you will get the result.